# Retain html client control values on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, postback, viewstate

How can I retain client side html controls on postback? I have tried setting `enableviewstate="true"` but that did not work. A workaround I've done was to build a server side function that takes all the posted values and resets them via `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` and call this on every postback method. Is there an easier and more time efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have have html control to keep their values on postback by making them runat="server" e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I need them to be client side controls.

Comment: I am doing a lot of javascript work with them, so I think I need them to be client side.. but now that I think about it, maybe I can do the same work with them being server side..

Comment: You can still work with them on the client even if they have they're running at the server.

Comment: Adding runat="server" doesn't mean you can't interact with them via javascript. They are still rendered on the client.

Comment: Getting Server control on client is lot more easier than keeping the client side and accessing their values on server. We can make viewstate like hidden field but I think it is doing what we already have.

Comment: Server controls get rendered as html controls. You can do anything you want with a server control in javascript - the only gotcha is that you have to work with the control's clientID - which is built based on the containers the control you are working with may be placed in.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone. I should've known. I'll give it a whirl

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the controls at every postback. If you're looking for something a little easier to implement, take a look at the [DynamicControlsPlaceholder](http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/DynamicControlsPlaceholder) control. It's a nifty little control that takes away most of the pain associated with persisting dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use **<kbd>HiddenField</kbd>**?

Now on clicking any button at client side, Preserve the data in **<kbd>HiddenField</kbd>**.

Use `JQuery document.ready` function to set the value again from **<kbd>HiddenField</kbd>** again. `JQuery docuemnt.ready` will be called on each `Postback`.